# Expo go crashing on ios simulator (expo React Native template app)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos, expo

I have problem with running expo, newly created app (empty Hello World!). It works perfectly with android studio emulator, but when I try to open it on the IOS simulator Expo go app is being installed, but app is not starting. It looks like crash without any errors in console (expo app splash screen is visible for a moment, then app disappears).

My Xcode app is updated

My dependencies:

```
    "expo": "~47.0.8",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.5"
```

I tried:

- granting different permissions for Xcode app on my macOS
- removing node_modules and package-lock.json and installing dependencies again (npm install)
- removing .expo directory
- using different ios simulators
- uninstalling expo app on simulators and resetting them
- I also followed expo documentation and I have Xcode command line tools installed (https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/ios-simulator/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you managed to find a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expo Go app in simulator closes automatically without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75313494/expo-go-app-in-simulator-closes-automatically-without-errors)

Answer (score 4):

You might need to install Rosetta if you are working on an M1 MacBook, because expo was created for intel chips.

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

[Expo Go app in simulator closes automatically without errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75313494/expo-go-app-in-simulator-closes-automatically-without-errors/75338582#75338582)