# Expo Go app in simulator closes automatically without errors

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode, simulator, expo-go

I want to create an (template) expo go app in VS Code with npm start. The (iOS) simulator opens, but the Expo Go app does not. When clicked it opens and immediately closes without any errors or warnings, neither in the terminal nor in the simulator.

I am using ruby v3.2.0, node v18.13.0, watchman 2023.01.30.00, npm 8.19.3. The dependencies in the package.json are below. I tried different versions of iOS simulators, but neither works (iPhone SE and iPhone 14). It does work on a device and in a browser. I tried reinstalling all systems and suggestions from https://blog.expo.dev/expo-sdk-43-aa9b3c7d5541.

Any ideas?

"dependencies": {
"expo": "~47.0.12",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem, if you are using a m1 macbook, you have to download rosetta because expo was created for intel chips.